# How to find the Fourier components

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis

I've got a sinusodial signal:

\begin{equation}
\Delta I=\cos(\Delta \omega t + \varphi)).
\end{equation}

and I would like to rewrite it as the sum of a cosine and a sine signal(without a phaseterm):

\begin{equation}
\Delta I = \mathcal{M}* \sin(\Delta \omega t) + \mathcal{N}* \cos(\Delta \omega t)
\end{equation}

My book ("Quantum Optics" by J.C. Garrison p. 293) does it, but I can't see how they got there.

If I perform a sin/cos transform I get the period of the signal as a factor:
\begin{align}
M(t) &= \mathcal{S}(\Delta I(\Delta\omega)) \\
 &= 4E_L E_P \int_{-T/2+t}^{T/2+t}cos(\Delta \omega \tau + \varphi))\sin(\Delta\omega)d\tau\\
 &= -4E_L E_P T \sin(\varphi) \\
\end{align}

I'm fairly certain, that I have to integrate over 
\begin{equation}
\cos(\Delta \omega \tau + \varphi))\sin(\Delta\omega) = \frac{1}{2}\left[ \sin(\varphi) + \sin(2\Delta\omega + \varphi) \right]
\end{equation} 
and 
$\cos(\Delta \omega \tau + \varphi))\cos(\Delta\omega)$ in order to remove the rapidly oscillating term $\sin(2\Delta\omega t)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use the relation $\cos(x+y)=\cos x \cos y - \sin x \sin y$? So

$$\cos(\Delta \omega t + \varphi))=\cos(\Delta\omega t)\cos\varphi-\sin(\Delta\omega t)\sin\varphi$$